# Examples of compact Kähler manifolds with $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\cap H^{1,1}(X)=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

As we know, Kodaira's embedding theorem can be put as:

*A compact Kähler manifold $X$ is projective if and only if $\mathcal K_X\cap H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\neq\emptyset$.*

Where $\mathcal K_X$ denotes the Kähler cone of $X$. 
So if we have $H^{1,1}(X)\cap H^2(X,\mathbb Z)=0$, we can make the conclusion that $X$ is not projective. And my question is:
Is there indeed exist any compact Kähler manifolds which satisfies $H^{1,1}(X)\cap H^2(X,\mathbb Z)=0$? To seek for such examples we should first limit ourselves to non-projective Kähler manifolds, for example, in dimension 2, we have K3 surfaces and complex tori, we know they have $h^{1,1}>0$, and I don't  know whether part of them satisfy $H^{1,1}(X)\cap H^2(X,\mathbb Z)=0$. So can anybody provide some examples? Any dimension is ok. Any comments are welcome, thanks!

Comment: As you guessed, some Tori have this property.

Answer (score 0):

For some constructions of non-projective Kähler manifolds, check this MO question:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257147/are-most-k%C3%A4hler-manifolds-non-projective

and the following article:
https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold

I quote the second article: For example, this is the case for the torus $\mathbb{C}^2/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is the lattice spanned by the vectors $(1,0), (0,1), (−\sqrt 2,−\sqrt 3), (−\sqrt 5,−\sqrt 7)$.

Comment: Isn't these 4 vectors linear dependent?

Comment: The vectors need not be linearly independent. You just need $4$ distinct points, so that you can generate a free abelian discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^2$. You can find more on this construction in Huybrechts' Complex Geometry, pages 57-58.

Comment: You mean any 4 distinct points may work? for example $(1,0), (0,1), (2,0), (0,2)$?

Comment: No, those don't work. You are right. The points need to be $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit why it satisfies $H^{1,1}(X)\cap H^2(X,\mathbb Z)=0$?